# Multiple columns $filter in SP designer 2013 http web service call

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, rest, designer-workflow, filter

How can I filter on multiple columns when making a web service call in a SP 2013 designer workflow? For example if this is the url for the service call then how is the `$filter` part different from what it is shown here for a single column:

```
https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/items?$filter=Column1 eq 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the AND operator to join the filters

```
https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/items?$filter=Column1 eq 1 AND Column2 eq 2 AND Column3 eq 3
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think of that. I didn't see any documentation on this either.

Comment: AND should be in small case like and